# Gorilla Mux 404

Tags: go, mux

I'm taking this holiday break to freshen up on Go. Unfortunately the code I have below is throwing a 404 on both of the routes. This is the latest iteration. I originally had the router in a handleRouter function and thought taking it out would fix the 404ing. Spoiler alert: it didn't. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Article struct {
    Title   string `json:"Title"`
    Desc    string `json:"desc"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
}

type Articles []Article

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Router v2 - Muxx")

    myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/all", returnAllArticles).Methods("GET")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello:")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homepage")
}

func returnAllArticles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    articles := Articles{
        Article{Title: "Hello", Desc: "Article Description", Content: "Article Content"},
        Article{Title: "Hello 2", Desc: "Article Description", Content: "Article Content"},
    }

    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllArticles")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(articles)

}
```

Comment: You're calling `http.ListenAndServe` without actually passing it your router. See the `http.Handle("/", r)` in the first example in the [`gorilla/mux` readme](https://github.com/gorilla/mux).

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a fine question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the router, you must pass it to the HTTP server.

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", myRouter))
```

or register it with the default serve mux:

```
http.Handle("/", myRouter)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
```

Comment: `http.Handle("/api", router1)` --> not found ? -- how to find this 
 `http.Handle("/", route2)` --> success